# Android Studio TextView showing numbers as letters

Tags: android, number-formatting

I have a problem with a TextView showing letters instead of numbers.

I am trying to make a converter app.

Here is my code:

```
package com.rickhuisman.converter;

import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class LengthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_length);
    }

    public void onClickConvertLength(View view) {
        // variables
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1Length);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2Length);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.convertButtonLength);
        // spinner 1
        String spinner1Value = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
        // spinner 2
        String spinner2Value = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
        EditText inputChecker = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputLength);
        TextView showText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTextLength);

        String inputCheckerText = inputChecker.getText().toString();
        EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputLength);

        // If input == 0
        if(inputCheckerText.equals("")) {
            inputCheckerLength();
        }


        // Millimeters && Millimeters
        else if(spinner1Value.equals("Millimeters") && spinner2Value.equals("Millimeters")) {
            // Get the input
            Double formule = new Double(input.getText().toString());

            methodLength(formule);
        }

        // Millimeters && Centimeters
        else if(spinner1Value.equals("Millimeters") && spinner2Value.equals("Centimeters")) {
            // Get the input
            Double formule = new Double(input.getText().toString());

            methodLength(formule);
        }
    }

    // If the input == 0
    public void inputCheckerLength() {
        TextView showText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTextLength);
        CharSequence toastText = "Nothing to convert!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastText, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    // The method
    public void methodLength(double formule) {
        TextView showText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTextLength);

        showText.setText(Double.valueOf(formule).toString());
    }
}
```

image of the code: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v05kr.png)

The problem is that if I put to many numbers in the EditText the TextView will show letters, is there a way I can make the TextView show the whole number and not letters?

Image of the problem:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1FW.png)

Sorry for the bad English and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `Double.toString()` method to output your `double` value, which uses the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) format.

If you want to display the plain number you can use `String.format()` instead:

```
showText.setText(String.format("%.0f", formule));
```

In case you want to show decimals you can use e.g. `%.2f` for two decimals instead of `%.0f`.